How to release the `bev` created at `accept_conn_cb` after socks5 data forwarding is complete?
I have implemented a socsk5 forwarding proxy service using libevent, but if a client uses this proxy service without Connection: close in the request header, the bev created in accept_conn_cb cannot be released.
Is there any way to get this bev to release?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <event2/event.h>
#include <event2/buffer.h>
#include <event2/bufferevent.h>
#include <event2/listener.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define SOCKS_ATYP_IPV6 4
#define RESPONSE_SIZE 10
#define SOCKS_VERSION 0x05
#define AUTH_METHOD_NO_AUTH 0x00
#define SOCKS_CMD_CONNECT 0x01
#define SOCKS_CMD_ASSOCIATE 0x03
#define SOCKS_ATYP_IPV4 0x01
#define SOCKS_ATYP_DOMAINNAME 0x03


void socks5_request(struct bufferevent *bev, void *ctx);
void event_cb(struct bufferevent *bev, short events, void *ctx);
void socks5_handshake(struct bufferevent *bev, void *ctx);
void write_cb(struct bufferevent *bev, void *ctx);
void forward_to_server(struct bufferevent *bev, void *ctx);
void forward_to_client(struct bufferevent *bev, void *ctx);
void accept_conn_cb(struct evconnlistener *listener, evutil_socket_t fd, struct sockaddr *address, int socklen, void *ctx);
void accept_error_cb(struct evconnlistener *listener, void *ctx);

void event_cb(struct bufferevent *bev, short events, void *ctx) {
    if (events & BEV_EVENT_ERROR) {
        perror("Error on bufferevent");
    }
    if (events & (BEV_EVENT_EOF | BEV_EVENT_ERROR)) {
        // Connection closed, free bufferevent
        printf("free bufferevent bev\n");
        bufferevent_free(bev);
    }
}

// socks5 handshake 
void socks5_handshake(struct bufferevent *bev, void *ctx) {
    struct evbuffer *input = bufferevent_get_input(bev);
    size_t len = evbuffer_get_length(input);
    unsigned char buffer[2];
    
    if (len < 2) {
        printf("need more data\n");
        return;
    }
    evbuffer_copyout(input, buffer, 2);
    if (buffer[0] != SOCKS_VERSION) {
        bufferevent_free(bev);
        evbuffer_drain(input, evbuffer_get_length(input));
        return;
    }

    // no auth
    unsigned char response[2] = {SOCKS_VERSION, AUTH_METHOD_NO_AUTH};
    bufferevent_write(bev, response, 2);

    // clean input
    evbuffer_drain(input, evbuffer_get_length(input));

    // handle socks5 request
    bufferevent_setcb(bev, socks5_request, NULL, event_cb, ctx);
}

// forward to server
void forward_to_server(struct bufferevent *bev, void *ctx) {
    struct bufferevent *server = ctx;
    struct evbuffer *input = bufferevent_get_input(bev);
    struct evbuffer *output = bufferevent_get_output(server);
    evbuffer_add_buffer(output, input);
}

// forward to client
void forward_to_client(struct bufferevent *bev, void *ctx) {
    struct bufferevent *client = ctx;
    struct evbuffer *input = bufferevent_get_input(bev);
    struct evbuffer *output = bufferevent_get_output(client);
    evbuffer_add_buffer(output, input);
}

// handle request
void socks5_request(struct bufferevent *bev, void *ctx) {
    struct evbuffer *input = bufferevent_get_input(bev);
    size_t len = evbuffer_get_length(input);
    unsigned char atyp;
    unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    if (len < 5) {
        printf("need more data\n");
        return;
    }

    evbuffer_copyout(input, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (buffer[1] != SOCKS_CMD_CONNECT) {
        printf("unsupported command %d\n", buffer[1]);
        bufferevent_free(bev);
        evbuffer_drain(input, len);
        return;
    }

    atyp = buffer[3]; // Address type (ATYP)

    if (atyp == SOCKS_ATYP_IPV4) {
        if (len < 10) return;

        unsigned char addr[4];
        unsigned char port[2];
        evbuffer_copyout(input, buffer, 4); // First 4 bytes of request
        evbuffer_drain(input, 4);
        evbuffer_remove(input, addr, 4); // Copy IPv4 address
        evbuffer_remove(input, port, 2); // Copy port

        char target_ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, addr, target_ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        int target_port = (port[0] << 8) | port[1];

        // connect dst
        struct event_base *base = bufferevent_get_base(bev);
        struct bufferevent *server = bufferevent_socket_new(base, -1, BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE);
        bufferevent_socket_connect_hostname(server, NULL, AF_INET, target_ip, target_port);

        // response success
        unsigned char response[10] = {SOCKS_VERSION, 0x00, 0x00, SOCKS_ATYP_IPV4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        bufferevent_write(bev, response, 10);

        bufferevent_setcb(bev, forward_to_server, NULL, event_cb, server);
        bufferevent_setcb(server, forward_to_client, NULL, event_cb, bev);
        bufferevent_enable(bev, EV_READ | EV_WRITE);
        bufferevent_enable(server, EV_READ | EV_WRITE);

        
    } else if (atyp == SOCKS_ATYP_DOMAINNAME) {
        
        int domain_len = buffer[4];
        char domain[256];
        memcpy(domain, &buffer[5], domain_len);
        domain[domain_len] = '\0';

        struct hostent *he = gethostbyname(domain);
        if (he == NULL) {
            printf("Failed to resolve domain: %s\n", domain);
            bufferevent_free(bev);
            evbuffer_drain(input, len);
            return;
        }

        struct sockaddr_in ipv4;
        memset(&ipv4, 0, sizeof(ipv4));
        ipv4.sin_family = AF_INET;
        memcpy(&ipv4.sin_addr, he->h_addr, he->h_length);
        memcpy(&ipv4.sin_port, &buffer[5 + domain_len], 2);

        struct event_base *base = bufferevent_get_base(bev);
        struct bufferevent *server = bufferevent_socket_new(base, -1, BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE);
        bufferevent_socket_connect(server, (struct sockaddr *)&ipv4, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        evbuffer_drain(input, 5 + domain_len + 2);

        // response success
        unsigned char response[10] = {SOCKS_VERSION, 0x00, 0x00, SOCKS_ATYP_IPV4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        bufferevent_write(bev, response, 10);

        bufferevent_setcb(bev, forward_to_server, NULL, event_cb, server);
        bufferevent_setcb(server, forward_to_client, NULL, event_cb, bev);
        bufferevent_enable(bev, EV_READ | EV_WRITE);
        bufferevent_enable(server, EV_READ | EV_WRITE);
    } else {
        bufferevent_free(bev);
    }

    evbuffer_drain(input, len);
}

// handle new accept
void accept_conn_cb(struct evconnlistener *listener, evutil_socket_t fd, struct sockaddr *address, int socklen, void *ctx) {
    struct event_base *base = evconnlistener_get_base(listener);
    struct bufferevent *bev = bufferevent_socket_new(base, fd, BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE);

    // set socks5_handshake
    bufferevent_setcb(bev, socks5_handshake, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    bufferevent_enable(bev, EV_READ | EV_WRITE);
}

// handle accept error
void accept_error_cb(struct evconnlistener *listener, void *ctx) {
    struct event_base *base = evconnlistener_get_base(listener);
    int err = EVUTIL_SOCKET_ERROR();
    fprintf(stderr, "Accept error %d (%s)\n", err, evutil_socket_error_to_string(err));
    event_base_loopexit(base, NULL);
}


int main()
{
    int port = 10802;
    
    struct event_base *base;
    struct evconnlistener *listener;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;

    // create base
    base = event_base_new();
    if (!base) {
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sin.sin_port = htons(port);

    listener = evconnlistener_new_bind(base, accept_conn_cb, NULL, LEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE | LEV_OPT_REUSEABLE, -1, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    if (!listener) {
        perror("evconnlistener_new_bind()");
        return 1;
    }

    evconnlistener_set_error_cb(listener, accept_error_cb);
    event_base_dispatch(base);

    evconnlistener_free(listener);
    event_base_free(base);
    
    return 0;
}

I tried to release both bev and server at event_cb like:
void event_cb(struct bufferevent *bev, short events, void *ctx) {
    struct bufferevent *client = ctx;
    if (events & BEV_EVENT_ERROR) {
        perror("Error on bufferevent");
    }
    if (events & (BEV_EVENT_EOF | BEV_EVENT_ERROR)) {
        // Connection closed, free bufferevent
        bufferevent_free(bev);
        if (client) {
            bufferevent_free(client);
        }
    }
}

Only set event_cb in bufferevent_setcb(server, forward_to_client, NULL, event_cb, bev); but it doesn't work.
update:
I'm currently using the method below, which temporarily solves the problem of not being able to close the bev, is there a better solution?
In socks5_request, add a timeout setting to bev and server, and then check for timeouts in the event_cb callbacks.
In socks5_request add:
    struct timeval read_timeout = {5, 0};  // 5 seconds
    struct timeval write_timeout = {5, 0}; // 5 seconds

    bufferevent_set_timeouts(bev, &read_timeout, &write_timeout);
    bufferevent_set_timeouts(server, &read_timeout, &write_timeout);

In event_cb add:
    if (events & BEV_EVENT_TIMEOUT) {
        if (bev) {
            bufferevent_free(bev);
        }
    }

